# Mute command in discord

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, mute

So im trying to make a command to mute people, and to unmute people, they work fine at adding the mute role and removing the mute role, but when I do mute someone they don't get muted and they can still talk, but i can see they have the muted role on them, and I disabled all talking permissions, and when someone sends a mute/unmute command without someones name the bot get an error saying Cannot read property `'roles' of undefined` here is the code:

```
else if (parts[0] === Prefix + 'mute') {
        const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g);
        const target = message.mentions.members.first();
        const mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
            (role) => role.name === 'Muted'
           );
           
           // if there is no `Muted` role, send an error
           if (!mutedRole)
            return message.channel.send('There is no Muted role on this server');
        target.roles.add(mutedRole);
        console.log(User + ' used the command ".mute ' + target + '"')
    
    } else if (parts[0] === Prefix + 'unmute') {
        const target = message.mentions.members.first();
        const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g);
        const mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
            (role) => role.name === 'Muted'
           );
           
           // if there is no `Muted` role, send an error
           if (!mutedRole)
            return message.channel.send('There is no Muted role on this server');
        target.roles.add(mutedRole); 
        setTimeout(() => {
            target.roles.remove(mutedRole); // remove the role
          }, ms(args[1]))
          console.log(User + ' used the command ".unmute ' + target + '"')
```

and when I see it in the console log I don't see the name if the person being muted/unmuted but I see there ID number

Answer (score 0):

For "not muting correctly", that is likely a Discord permissions issue, so we can't help you resolve that here.

As for the command without someone's name, you try to do `target.roles` while `target` is undefined, hence the error. You need to make sure `target` is not undefined and, if it is, throw an error to the user (just like with `mutedRole`).

Comment: thanks but the muted role is set up corretly and I searched on google why it's not working it is because of the other roles, but when I try getting rid of peoples roles it works but giving them back is the hard part